# WCF Service Reference is not being updated properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf

I created a WCF Windows Service with an Interface containing:

```
[OperationContract]
string /* errMessage */ CreateDirectoryIfNotExists(string fullFolderPath);
```

The service reference for this in a test application was ok.
I then decided to make the methods async, so changed my interface calls to:

```
[OperationContract]
Task<string> /* errMessage */ CreateDirectoryIfNotExistsAsync(string fullFolderPath);
```

This compiles ok, but when I re-install the service and get the Service Reference I see both old and new method formats!

[image]

How do I get rid of the old method format from the Service reference?

I presume something needs to be deleted or rebuilt but I don't know what?

Comment: I try updating one of the methods when updating service reference but it fails. If you won't use  the older method any more, you may annotate it.

Comment: Thanks @Jaiyao but the older methods are already deleted from the C#, they just won't go away from the service reference!

Comment: Update: I have tried changing the endpoint address to http://localhost:8001 but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved the mystery.
I renamed my async methods to see what happened, by removing the final 'c' character:

```
CreateDirectoryIfNotExistsAsyn
```

Now I get the following:

[image]

Note that the first method, with the same name as my async one, is NOT the async version.
So, I conclude that when you define an async method WCF does the following:

- Automatically adds a non-async method.
- Modifies the names so that one
  has "Async" on the end and the other doesn't.

I have no idea what would happen if you called the non-async one, which is not defined in my code.

Can anyone confirm this behaviour?

Comment: Update: I have now tried both methods, and they both work as expected.  I put in an artificial delay, and they both  take the same amount of time.  WCF must be wrapping the non-async call in an async call with an await.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have deleted the method from the C#, you may try using the `update service reference` in VS. After updating, the method you deleted will not appear in Object Browser.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but you have misunderstood.  The method was always deleted from the C#, and I was using "Update reference".